# Windows Phone 7 CTP Refresh to Beta Build Conversion

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

> **EDIT:** I modified the question title
>   after understanding the actual
>   problem.

I tried to run the sample RSS reader from [Codeplex](http://rssr7.codeplex.com/). I tried it on CTP version of the Windows Phone Developer Tools and it worked  ok on that.

But now after trying it on beta version of the tools, it gave me following error.

```
The type or namespace name 'Phone' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' 
(are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Its not able to  locate the assembly `Microsoft.Phone.Controls`. Though I've installed beta tools successfully on my machine.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are large changes in the namespaces and dlls between CTP and Beta. Most of the Microsoft.Phone namespaces have been merged into a single dll, when in the CTP they were in separate dlls.

You'll need to basically remove the invalid references you see in the project tree, and then resolve the missing references in each file.

Comment: Thanks Ben.Below, I've posted a link which tells the specific changes that should be made while converting the CTP app to beta.